# Can I move test cases from test lab to test plan to make duplicate set of test cases at test plan

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm, hp-alm-12.20, hp-alm-12.01

I have some 200 TCs in Test plan (say folder 1) and so in test lab, now I want to create a duplicate set of same 200 TCs in test plan (say folder 2) with the help of test lab in one go without copy pasting each TC each time since these TCs are randomly placed and can not be copy pasted in one go. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: You can duplicate the test set in the test lab without duplicating the tests in the test plan

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to copy test cases from test lab to test plan. Actually test lab doesn't have any test cases, it only has a reference to test plan's test cases. So only way to copy test cases is from test plan to test plan.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

1. Go to Test Lab and select a test set which you want to move.
2. Click on Select Tests button present on top of grid view of test cases.
3. After clicking it, a pane at the right side of the window will get opened.
4. Collapse the hierarchy and go to the folder from which you want to get the test set.
5. Select that test set and Click on (<-) left arrow, green in color.
6. You will be prompt to add all number of test cases in that test to the selected test set
7. Click Yes and all test cases in selected test set will be moved in it

(I just do it myself, saw some blogs but couldn't get any help. Somehow, do it on my own :D)